# Modify this code (downloading image) to upload image to a specific URL

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, progressdialog

I am able to upload image using volley but am unable to sync it with progress dialog. I want a progress dialog synced with the size/time it takes to download that file.

I am using below code to download image:

```
       @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return "completed";
    }
```

I want changes in the above code so that it could work for uploading images.